# jQuery add rows dynamically - maximum 10

Tags: jquery

I am adding table rows dynamically with unique input/label names. However, I only want for a user to be able to add max 6 rows.

I tried using lastid < 7 but it doesn't work. Any suggestions?

```
function addTableRow(jQtable) {
   var lastId = jQtable.find("tr:last td:first input").attr("id");
   var newId = parseInt(lastId);

    var row = $('<tr />');

    for (var i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
        var thisId = newId + 1;
        var cell = $('<td />');
        var label = $('<label for="' + thisId + '">' + thisId + '</label>');
        var input = $('<input type="text" name="' + thisId + '" id="' + thisId + '" />');
        cell.append(label, input);
        row.append(cell);
    }
    jQtable.append(row);
    }

   $('#addRow').click(function() {
   addTableRow($('#mans'));
  });
```

Comment: While appending tr you have to check the length of tr must be less then your maxValue, `.length()`  or `.size()` gives count of tr

Comment: Recommend doing this via template based data binding and not dynamic html... Look at KnockoutJS, JQuery templates etc

Comment: It looks like you're using numeric-only IDs. This isn't valid HTML. Also, you're not actually changing the value of thisID in each iteration of your loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set up a counter variable. You can use a global, but I prefer to set it on the element itself using [`.data`](http://api.jquery.com/data):

```
$('#addRow').click(function() {
     var $mans = $('#mans');
     var c = $mans.data('counter') || 0;
     if (c<=6) {
         $mans.data('counter',(c+1));
         addTableRow($mans);
     }
});
```